# bootstrap nav on carousel slider

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want nav-tabs works on a carousel slider by using position:absolute
but its not working and the nav-tabs become disorganized

here is the html code

```
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- nav -->
<nav id="nav1" class="row">
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-4"<br><a>home
</a></li>
            <li class="col-lg-2"><a>search</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     </nav>
    <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
```

and css code is this

```
#nav1{
z-index:100;
}

.carousel-inner{
position:absolute;
margin-top:0px;
}

<!-- slider -->

  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
  }
```

can you help me

Comment: Can you put together a jsfiddle?